# How to search a char in a char array in if condition statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, char

Is there any function which can help me do the following much more easily?

```
char ch = '+';
if (( ch == '+') || (ch == '-') || (ch == '*'))
{
    //do something
}
```

Since have to check this several times in my code, I would prefer if there was any to do it similar to

```
char arr ={'+','-','*'};
if (ch in arr)
{
    //do something 
}
```

Comment: What makes you think the existing code is not "efficient"? Can you show us your benchmarks that show it is a bottleneck in your code, and your research that shows it can be improved upon?

Comment: Now if you want this so that your code is more maintainable and expressive, that's completely reasonable :)

Comment: You could use something like `std::find` or `std::any_of` but as @BoundaryImposition said I'd be surprised if that would be a performance win over your first version.

Comment: [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)? [`std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)? [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition It is not running time which becomes problematic, it is the typing time. In the actual code I have to check between seven characters, and do it thrice. As you said, I was just wondering if there was some way which could make the code more maintainable and easier to write :)

Comment: @firstlegagain1: Okay, so "efficiency" is actually the wrong word.

Comment: I admit my mistake on this part

Comment: If you are repeating these checks in many places, you can, of course, wrap them in your own function just like you would any repeated code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you can use:

```
if ( std::strchr("+-*", ch) )
```

The `strchr` function, from `#include <cstring>`, returns a null pointer iff the character is not found in the string.

Comment: Thanks! This helped. Would have been better to mention I needed to #include <cstring> to make the function run

Comment: @firstlegagain1 cool... I added that now. You can type function names into cppreference.com and it'll bring up which header that function is from

Comment: Why use C functions?
`std::array<char, size> arr{ /* ... */ }; if (std::find(arr.cbegin(), arr.cend(), '+') == arr.cend() || /* ... */) { }`
could be used.

Comment: @6EQUJ5 because it's simple, clear, and concise.  I don't have a prejudice against perfectly usable functions just because other languages also offer the same function

Comment: @M.M This **is** a question about C++, though. I wouldn't call it prejudice.

Comment: @6EQUJ5 `std::strchr` is mandated by the C++ Standard, and not deprecated. It is just as much a part of C++ as any other function mandated by said document

Comment: @M.M Yes, technically it is in the C++ standard library. "I don't have a prejudice against perfectly usable functions just because other languages also offer the same function" other languages?

Comment: @6EQUJ5: Your suggested alternative is substantially messier and more verbose than even the original code, let alone MM's suggestion.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Yes, it is. `std::strchr` only works on C-strings. `std::find_first_of` could be an alternative. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of

Comment: @6EQUJ5: [You are mistaken](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2c53681eeb0b088).

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Wow, I completely misunderstood. This answer and the OP wants to find if a char exists in a char array (in the dang title). I misunderstood it as: How to search if any one of these chars exist in the char array. Sorry, for all the misunderstanding. I better read carefully.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition `std::find(str.begin(), str.end(), value)` vs `std::find_first_of(str.begin(), str.end(), search_str.begin(), search_str.end())`

Comment: @6EQUJ5: Regardless of what the question is, your claim that _"`std::strchr` only works on C-strings"_ is false, as demonstrated.

Comment: I guess I should note that my solution would not work if `ch` could be the null character

Comment: The fact that a function isn't deprecated doesn't mean that it's always fine to use it when you so please (take `std::rand`). They're mostly left there for backwards compatibility, not new code.  `-1` from me.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a function that generates code equivalent to

```
if (( ch == '+') || (ch == '-') || (ch == '*'))
```

with a better user syntax.

---

```
template <typename X>
bool any(const X&) noexcept
{
    return false;
}

template <typename X, typename T, typename... Ts>
bool any(const X& x, const T& curr, const Ts&... rest) noexcept
{
    return x == curr || any(x, rest...);
}
```

Usage:

```
if(any(ch, '+', '-', '*')) { /* do something */ }
```

As shown [by this **godbolt.org** comparison](https://godbolt.org/g/0dnYG0), this is an example of a **zero-cost abstraction**.

In C++17 you could use a [*fold expression*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
template <typename X, typename... Ts>
bool any(const X& x, const Ts&... rest)
{
    return ((x == rest) || ...);
}
```

---

If you want to reuse the same comparison values multiple times without repeating yourself, you can create a "curried" version of `any` that first binds the arguments to check against and then does the comparison on a subsequent call.

```
template <typename... Ts>
auto bound_any(const Ts&... xs)
{
    return [xs...](const auto& x)
    {
        return ((x == xs) || ...);
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
auto is_op = bound_any('+', '-', '*');
if(is_op(ch)) { /* do something */ }
```

Here's [a **godbolt.org** comparison](https://godbolt.org/g/k6KQOb).

Comment: Your function's name isn't very good, and you also don't allow for doing this in multiple parts of the code without repeating yourself (which seems to be what the OP is concerned about)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: agreed on the function name. I added a curried version to avoid repetition.

Comment: Thanks! Although I am a beginner, so I am afraid I did not understand a lot of the code. I will search it up tho and try to understand

Comment: Better now, but ultimately over-engineered. :)

Comment: is `noexcept` necessary or even advisable? In the general case, perhaps the class overloads operators in a way that means they can throw

Comment: @M.M: a conditional `noexcept` is advisable, but in truth I just blindly copied my test code from godbolt.org where I knew that no exceptions could have been thrown :)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: why do you say that this is over-engineered?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: thanks for the great argumentation, you convinced me to not write such over-engineered code in the future. /s Generic programming is not over-engineering.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Lol.

Comment: Replacing three `==` and two `||` with a complicated function that will be understood by maybe 2% of the C++ population, and supported in _maybe_ 5% of C++ environments (and is not even standard yet), is over-engineering. Case in point: the OP above has absolutely no idea how your suggestion works. It's clever, but it's not practical.

Comment: How is `((x == rest) || ...)` complicated? The OP has not idea how it works because, as he/she mentioned, he/she is a beginner. Furthermore, I think that this is a great opportunity for the OP to get acquainted with more advanced C++ features such as *variadic templates* that make the language so powerful. I also don't think there is anything clever about this - it's **trivial** usage of variadic templates to avoid code repetition and increase genericity. I agree with you on the portability issue, but the C++14 version is only slightly longer and not more complicated if recursion is understood

Comment: The main benefits of this solutions are **genericity** and **no unnecessary overhead**. If the OP knows that he/she will always need to compare against a set of characters, [M.M's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/m-m) is a fantastic choice. If the OP wants to generalize the idea of "comparing something against a set of values known at compile-time", my solution is more appropriate and definitely not over-engineered. It depends on the problem.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: FYI, unless you tag me with `@BoundaryImposition`, I do not get notified about your replies.

Comment: I too think this is mostly over-engineered, but two things salvage it: (1) the original is "under-engineered" (repetitive, error-prone) and (2) the c++17 is readable and succinct. I think the answer is therefore just informative and insightful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
   char arr[] ={'+','-','*'};
   char ch = '-';
   if(std::find(arr, arr+sizeof(arr)/sizeof(char), ch) - arr < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(char)){
   //do anything 
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The hardcoded `3` could be improved, don't you think?

Comment: I have edited my answer, Is that ok ? Thank you for telling me.

Comment: I'd consider using `std::array`, that way you can simply use `.size()` instead of the sizeof trick.

Comment: Sure you are right, but I was trying to answer this particular question and I tried to use char arr[] just like the question. Am I right or what ? I am trying to be useful here. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

This makes `any` a compile time construct if your array is too. I can't really think of a way to make this more optimized if the range is arbitrary.

I've chosen to overload `==` because it looks nicer than passing the arguments side by side.

```
#include<iterator>

template<typename Iter>
class any
{
public:
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type;

    constexpr any(Iter begin, Iter end) : begin{begin}, end{end} {}
    template<typename T, size_t N>
    constexpr any(T (&arr)[N]) : any{arr, arr + N} {}

    constexpr bool operator==(const value_type& v)
    {
        return compare(v, begin);
    }
private:
    Iter begin, end;
    constexpr bool compare(const value_type& v, Iter it)
    {
        return it != end && (v == *it || compare(v, it + 1));
    }
};

template<typename T, size_t N>
any(T (&)[N]) -> any<T*>;

template<typename T, typename Iter>
constexpr bool operator==(const T& t, any<Iter> a)
{
    return a == t;
}
```

This results in a nice looking format

```
static_assert('+' == any("+-*"), "Failure!");

constexpr char ops[] = {'+', '-', '*'};
char c = '/';
if(c == any(ops))
    do_stuff(c);
```

#### Explanations

```
using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type;
```

is to alias the type `Iter` dereferences to as `value_type`.

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
any(T (&)[N]) -> any<T*>;
```

is to [deduct the type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_deduction) of `any` without explicit template parameters.

```
return it != end && (v == *it || compare(v, it + 1));
```

is to recursively check if the range has been exhausted and if not, check if the value is equal to the current element.

Note that `any("+-*")` has **4** characters in it, the last one being `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, at first glance, this is a set lookup: *is this element any of those* is equivalent to *does this set of elements contain this one*. And, as such:

```
if ((std::set<char> {'a','b','c'}).count(x) > 0) {
    // ...
}
```

[See it on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9adfbf142a566cde)

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case, you can wrap the boolean expression in your own custom function:

```
bool isOperator(char ch) {
    return ( ch == '+') || (ch == '-') || (ch == '*');
}
```

This will reduce the redundancy in the rest of your code since now you can just do

```
if(isOperator(ch))
```